# Programmatically downloading a file from Sharepoint without using Web Services?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, webdav, frontpage-extensions

I'd like to fetch some files from a SharePoint site, however I do not want to use the web services as a) I want to be compatible with both 2007 and 2010 and b) I'm not sure if Web Services can give me all files on a site.

SharePoint Designer can do that, and it seems to use FrontPage Server Extensions using _vti_bin/Author.dll. Also, I can access it in Windows using Map Network Drive -> Map Web Site, which *I think* is using WebDAV.

Is there any C# implementation of either a WebDAV Client or a Author.dll Client?

Comment: Honestly, the likelihood of the Web Services interface to remain compatible between 2007 and 2010 is much, much higher than the likelihood of the private interface between SP and SP designer staying compatible.

Comment: @Timores I've tested that with 2007 SP2 and 2010 Beta and the interface is the same, SP Designer uses Front Page Server Extensions which are "stable" since 5 years or so and even though they are End of Life, they are still used.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I read that SP designer 2010 only works with SP 2010, so I thought the interface had changed.
But I do think that the WS interface will be stable, too. I apologize for insisting, but it seems to me that WS are the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this code to download.  http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/10/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document.html.  Just search around for different upload code and mess with it.  I would give you my code for uploading files but I am on vacation and I promised myself that I would not log into work :).  That link should get you pointed in the right direction.